# Creating Stacked Histograms Graph using pyqtgraph BarGraphItem

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I'd like to create a stacked histogram from multiple arrays of different lengths. Is this possible with numpy and pyqtgraph?

[image: stacked histogram]